# Export images from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets sheet that creates QR images from the Google charts API using the IMAGE function that takes a URL to encode as an argument.  I would like to export the created images to an image file,  say a JPG.   Problem is Sheets does not recognize the cell content as an image so SHIFT +  Right click does not show the Save Image As in the context menu.  Any ideas on how to export all of these to separate files.

Comment: If you have the list of URLs it can be script that will loop through the list, make images and save them into some folder on Google Drive. I'm sure it will be about the same images that you have already on your sheet. As a non-script workaround you can try to export the sheet into PDF or Excel and try to get images from there.

Comment: What I have is a script that loops through all the shapes on the sheet.  I then copy each and paste to a Chart which is cleared for each new pass.  I do a copy of the shape and paste to the blank chart.  This puts the image in the upper left corner.  I export the chart to a JPEG but this creates a  picture with the small image on the full size sheet.  There is no way to size the chart page other than to use page format to set the paper size for the export which I assume would work like a print.   I would need a printer that could be set for say a 3"x3" paper to make the image a little smaller.

Comment: Continued... So my only alternative is to use a photo editor to crop and resize but I do not have updated program to automate this activity.

Comment: And where are the QR images on this grand scheme? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

Comment: Images are created with formula in column E  such as =image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl="&D2).   The encoded data is from cell D2.

Comment: BTW... the process of saving to a chart was not done in Google SHeets.  I did that in Excel with similar sheets using a different QR code API but issue there was images were not embedded in the SS cells. They were Linked Images and could not be saved directly. Sorry about that comment but I did this when I could not figure out how to export the images from Sheets.

Comment: So @RemcoE33 answer should work for you. It, supposedly, takes all formulas from a column (column 'A' in that case), gets QR codes via Google API and saves them into Google Drive folder. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes it worked.  But I need to modify it to save each with unique name and find code to have the same resolution and size as in the ss.  They appear to be saved in a different resolution of the QR image and size as displayed when viewing the jpg.

Comment: I not an expert in qr-code generation. The formula  `=image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&D2)` supposedly should get you a picture 300x300 px with the link from cell 'D2'. Doesn't it work? You can try `chs=600x600` As for the names. Probably you can use `blob.setName(name)` to set any name for a just created blob/file. You need to figure out how the names could be designed: from urls, or from some column with names, or it could be just numbers.

Comment: I got the image okay in the worksheet.  However when I used the script to reference that image,  make a copy as blob and then save to jpeg,  the jpeg image looked like it was created from a smaller   size x size parameter.  This leads me to believe the images were recreated in doing the copy to a blog and not having the same parameters.  I have stopped developing this app so I will not be implementing any further suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Download the sheet in Microsoft Excel .xlsx format by going to the File > Download menu.

Then open the .xlsx file in your computer using any unzip program (e.g. 7z) and navigate to ../xl/media in the zip file. All the images would be there - extract where you want them.

Answer (score 3):

This will fit your needs:

1. Tools -> Script editor
2. Clear the little code you see
3. Paste the code from below
4. Change sheetname (now Data) to your needs
5. sheet.getRange(2,1, ..... This assumes your images starting at row 2 in the first column (A). Change this to fit your needs.
6. Changed the folder id to the folder you want the images. (found in url)
7. Hit run -> Give permission (once)

Look at the folder.

**The script:**

```
function isImageToImage(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  const formulas = sheet.getRange(2,1, sheet.getLastRow()-1).getFormulas().flat();
  const urls = formulas.map(formula => {
    return /\"(.*?)\"/gmi.exec(formula)[1]
  })

  
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1QVo_pr_Wo6xxxxxxxxx9Yx')

  urls.forEach(url => {
    console.log(url)
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    folder.createFile(blob)
  })

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It worked  and the basic functionality is there.  I need to add a file name convention to name each separate image.  Right now the all name as Chart.PNG.  need to figure out how to get that info into the loop.  Also there is an issue with the saved image resolution.  The image on the SS are 300x300.  Does this script recreate the API call and regenerate an image?  If so need to add something to the formula that causes the image to be created with the higher resolution.  As is they are default size and not very detailed QR codes.   Looking for more pixel resolution.